# I can not drag conteneditable div using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a div drag and drop while that div is `contenteditable="true"` using jquery.But i cant do this using below code,

```
  $('#editabledrag').draggable()
                        .click(function(){
                            $(this).draggable({disabled:false });
                        })
      .dblclick(function(){

        $(this).draggable({disabled : true});
      });
```

My jsp :

```
<div class='example' id="content">
<div id="editabledrag" contenteditable="true" style="position: fixed;z-index:10000000">
click and type!.
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/ux3k0t23/14/

I hope i am doing right code but why i can not drag and drop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.draggable()` is a function that is [implemented in the jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and you didnt include jQuery UI in your fiddle.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux3k0t23/19/)

In your JSP code add the following script which has Google CDN for jQuery UI before `</body>` and after including the main jQuery library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You Mr.Rahul.I understand the issue.